# PHP date format error

Tags: php, date, format

I have an array with a key timestamp with the following content

> "timestamp" => "2011-11-29 00:00:00"

When i try to change the format using this

```
date("F j, Y", $data['Visitor']['timestamp']);
```

i get the following error

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on the datetime data to convert it into Unix timestamp first.

```
date("F j, Y", strtotime($data['Visitor']['timestamp']));
```

Checkout the documentation of [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) it accept a Unix timestamp as a second parameter and you are passing a datetime value.

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/eLEQf2IK)

Answer (score 1):

The function requires the [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is numeric - and not a string formatted date.

As @Shakti Singh mentions you should use strtotime for that.

From the PHP docs on the timestamp parameter:

> The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that
>   defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. In
>   other words, it defaults to the value of time().

Answer (score 0):

A newer way to do this as of PHP 5.2 is the [DateTime class](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eUY3B2):

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2011-11-29 00:00:00');
echo $datetime->format('F j, Y');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eUY3B2)